# How to deal with quotecharacters within quotecharacters in CSV files?

Tags: python, regex, csv, twitter

I am building a twitter scraper in python, which I would like to scrape my home timeline and create a readable CSV file with the tweet ID, tweet creator, timestamp, and tweet content. Tweets often contain commas, (the delimiter I am using) which is not an issue when the tweet content column is wrapped in single quotes (the quotechar I am using) . However, due to the limitations of the twitter api, some tweets contain single quotes and commas, which confuses the CSV reader into treating commas within tweets as delimiters.

I have attempted to use regular expressions to remove or replace the single quotes within the actual quotecharacters I would like to keep, but I have not found a way to do so.

Here is what tweets.txt looks like:

```
ID,Creator,Timestamp,Tweet
1112783967302844417,twitteruser,Mon Apr 01 18:29:06 +0000 2019,'At Adobe's summit, 'experience' was everywhere'
```

Here is my python script:

```
import csv

with open ('tweets.txt','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',', quotechar="'")
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

I would like to recieve an output like this:

```
['ID', 'Creator', 'Timestamp', 'Tweet']
['1112783967302844417', 'twitteruser', 'Mon Apr 01 18:29:06 +0000 2019', 'At Adobe^s summit, ^experience^ was everywhere']
```

But currently, the fact that the tweet content contains single quotes within makes it so that the csv reader recognizes the commas as delimiters, and gives this output:

```
['ID', 'Creator', 'Timestamp', 'Tweet']
['1112783967302844417', 'twitteruser', 'Mon Apr 01 18:29:06 +0000 2019', 'At Adobes summit', " 'experience' was everywhere'"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case where you know the number of columns in your CSV, and where only the last is free text containing commas, you could use Python's string methods:

```
with open ('tweets.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        l = (line.strip()                  # Get rid of newlines
                 .split(",", 3))           # Get four columns
        l[-1] = (l[-1].strip("'")          # Remove flanking single quotes
                      .replace("'", "^"))  # Replace inner single quotes if required
        print(l)
```

This code as many limitations, and will fit your current case only.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is using regex. It's not the best solution but it's a start. I think there's some other choices that could be made to avoid this problem to begin with, for example writing these records to a database. Or when writing to the file, properly escaping quotes.

```
import re

line_pattern = r'([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)'

with open ('tweets.txt','r') as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file.readlines():

        match_obj = re.match(line_pattern, line)

        id_ = match_obj.group(1)
        creator = match_obj.group(2)
        timestamp = match_obj.group(3)
        tweet = match_obj.group(4).strip("'")  # clean quotes off ends

        print([id_, creator, timestamp, tweet])
```

Please note this solution is not flexible in anyway. It also works only if the first three columns don't have commas. But like I said, there's improvements to be made before getting to this point that would avoid this problem to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a non-standard input format, you should use your own parser. For instance, you can use a simple RegEx to parse the records.

For instance, the RegEx `"([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),'?(.*?)'?$"` can parse the the header and the tweets. A tweet can be quoted or not.

Here is the code:

```py
import re

match_record = re.compile(r"([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),'?(.*?)'?$").match

with open('tweets.txt', mode='r', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        line = line.strip()
        mo = match_record(line)
        record = mo.groups()
        print(record)
```

Don’t forget to specify the file encoding (I made the assumption it is "utf-8")…